# how to load image name from database and load it into my imageview

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i have a project in which i have in my db images stored with their names only so i want to load those image with javafx

and i have no idea how to load thos images

```
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

   // help me here to retreive my images names
   }
```

and this is my button that allows me to change my cover picture
here is the code

```
  changecover.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

                //Set extension filter
                FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
                FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
                fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

                //Show open file dialog
                File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
                Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
                coverpic.setImage(image);
                Groupe g = gs.getGroupe(5);
                g.setPhoto_couverture(coverpic.toString());
                gs.update(g);
                //myImageView.setImage(image);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Groupe_homeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Why you need to use Buffered image? You can read them directly using JavaFX Image -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html using (file:absolutefilepath) . Then store them into an array of images and read them :) . Mention also that reading a ton of images will crash Java VM .

Answer (score 0):

Why load the image data to a `BufferedImage` and then convert this `BufferedImage` to a JavaFX `Image` when you can avoid storing the image data in memory twice by directly loading the data to a `Image`:

```
Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

I'm not sure how a database is involved here though, since `FileChooser` allows you to choose the image from storage devices available to the client only, which means you'd need to implement some way of retrieving the data from the server... (unless the database is for use on the local machine only)